# facebook friends list

Tags: c#, facebook, api

I want to get my facebook friend list and their email using c#.net with facebook api.

I it possible?

Thanks.

Comment: Yes it is possible. The API has methods to do this, I suggest digging into the API documentation. http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is.

Check the [Facebook API](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/)